Fourier coefficients least squares property proof
I'm currently working through the T. Chihara "Introduction into ortghogonal polynomials" book, and the problem 3.5 of the book is to proof the least squares property:

Suppose a moment functional $\mathcal{L}[f]$ is defined as $\int_a^b f(x)w(x)dx$, where $w(x) > 0$ is a weight function, and let $\{p_n(x)\}$ denote the corresponding sequence of orthonormal polynomials. If $f$ is any complex-valued function such that $\mathcal{L}\{|f(x)|^2\} = \int_a^b|f(x)|^2w(x)dx$ exists, let $s_n(x) = s_n(f; x) = \Sigma_{k=0}^n c_k p_k(x), c_k = \mathcal{L}[f(x)p_k(x)]$. Prove that $\mathcal{L}[|f(x) - s_n(x)|^2] < \mathcal{L}[|f(x) - t_n(x)|^2]$ for every $t_n(x) = \Sigma_{k=0}^n b_k p_k(x)$ such that $b_i \neq c_i$ for at least one $i$.

The important note there is that the book uses the following definitions for orthogonality and orthonormality:


$P_n(x)$ is a complex polynomial of degree $n$
$\mathcal{L}[P_n(x)P_m(x)] = 0$ if $m \neq n$
$\mathcal{L}[P_n(x)^2] \neq 0 $
(Orthonormality) $\mathcal{L}[P_n(x)^2] = 1$


The definition 8.10 of an orthogonal resp. orthonormal sequence of functions in the Rudin PMA is different:


$\int_a^b \phi_m(x) \overline{\phi_n(x)} dx = 0, (m \neq n)$
$\int_a^b |\phi_n(x)|^2dx = 1$


And with this definition the proof is straightforward, since after expanding the expression $\mathcal{L}[|f(x) - t_n(x)|^2]$ we can apply it to obtain:

$\int_a^b (f - t_n)(\overline{f} - \overline{t_n}) wdx = \mathcal{L}[|f|^2] - \int_a^b f \Sigma_m \overline{b_m} \overline{p_m} w dx - \int_a^b \overline{f} \Sigma_m b_m p_m w dx + \mathcal{L}[t_n \overline{t_n}] = \mathcal{L}[|f|^2] - \Sigma_m c_m \overline{b_m} - \Sigma_m \overline{c_m} b_m + \Sigma_m |b_m|^2 = L[|f|^2] - \Sigma_m |c_m|^2 + \Sigma_m |c_m - b_m|^2 $

However, I cannot apply the Chihara definition to handle the cross-terms $\int_a^b f \Sigma_m \overline{b_m} \overline{p_m} w dx$ and its counterpart, since the definition does not involve the complex conjugate. The $\int_a^b p_n(x)p_m(x)w(x)dx = 0$ does not imply $\int_a^b p_n(x)\overline{p_m(x)}w(x)dx = 0$ in general, although if it would, it would make the thing provable. How can I work around this?
